# How to combine/merge rows in SPSS Modeler?

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

Please advice how to transform the original dataset to the expected output as shown below on SPSS Modeler?

It is expected to merge the values of all rows shared the same ID No.

[image: Original dataset]

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SPSS syntax is availabel to you, the following aggregation command should do the trick:

```
aggregate outfile=* /break=ID /date_1 from_1 to_1 date_2 from_2 to_2=
                           max(date_1 from_1 to_1 date_2 from_2 to_2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!
I could replicate with equivalent process with the Aggregation Node at SPSS Modeler and got the expected output